# getSignaturesForAddress limited to 1000 TXNs

Tags: solana-program

This is my Code, the output is 1000, I tried with another address which had 18 TXNs & the output was 18 , the wallet below has more than a million transactions, Solana/web3js is limited to fetch 1000 Txns , please let me know if there is any other way to get the rest and exact number

```
const SrchAddress = "5HcS2Qej4uPKop4pNaDHnVywx42Y2qUhceUYmbFKPG8g";
const endpoint = "https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com";

const SolanaConnection = new solanaweb3.Connection(endpoint);
const getTransactions = async (address) => {
    const pubkey = new solanaweb3.PublicKey(address);
    let transactionList = await SolanaConnection.getSignaturesForAddress(pubkey);
    console.log(transactionList.length);
};

getTransactions(SrchAddress);
```

Comment: hey, if you found either of the answers useful, could you please mark the question as answered?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since `getSignaturesForAddress` returns 1000 objects at the maximum, you will need to add a recursive loop that leverages the `{before: "signature"}` option to get all of the signatures that you need.

This is going to be an incredibly slow call, but I added a bit of logging so you can see that the list of transactions is growing.

```
const SrchAddress = "5HcS2Qej4uPKop4pNaDHnVywx42Y2qUhceUYmbFKPG8g";
const endpoint = "https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com";

const SolanaConnection = new solanaweb3.Connection(endpoint);
const getTransactions = async (address) => {
    let transactionListLength = 1000
    const allTransactions = []
    const pubkey = new solanaweb3.PublicKey(address);
    let transactionList = await SolanaConnection.getSignaturesForAddress(pubkey);
    allTransactions.push(transactionList)
    while (transactionListLength >= 1000) {
      const lastSignature = transactionList[transactionList.length - 1];
      const nextSignatures = await SolanaConnection.getSignaturesForAddress(pubkey, { before: lastSignature.signature });
      allTransactions.push(nextSignatures)
      transactionList = nextSignatures
      transactionListLength = nextSignatures.length;
      console.log('current:',transactionList.length);
      console.log('total:',allTransactions.length)
    }
  return allTransactions.flat()
};

getTransactions(SrchAddress).then((res) => console.log(res))
```

This loop will keep going until the returned object's length is less than the 1000 transactions, meaning you've reached the end of the list.

Comment: Ive tried implementing the above with "Getparsedtransactions" but no luck https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getParsedTransactions. I was expecting a more redeable value that includes the from and the to address as well as the lamport

Answer (score 4):

The [getSignatureForAddresses](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getSignaturesForAddress) method returns a maximum of 1000 signatures.

To retrieve signatures older than your initial query, you can pass in an optional `before` signature. https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/modules.html#SignaturesForAddressOptions

> Start searching backwards from this transaction signature.

```
let transactionList = await SolanaConnection.getSignaturesForAddress(pubkey);
const lastSignature = transactionList[transactionList.lenght - 1];
const nextSingatures = await SolanaConnection.getSignaturesForAddress(pubkey, { before: lastSignature });
```

Comment: So that helped me with getting another 1000 of those TXNs, though my main concern is to get all the TXNs of a wallet

Comment: You'll have to call this in a recursive manner. Continue to call the `getSignatureForAddress` method with the last signature from the previous return until `getSignatureForAddress` doesn't return any more results.

Recursion: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/quick-intro-to-recursion/