# How to find all transfers for a specific token

Tags: spl-token, rpc, transfer, historical-data

Is there a way to find all transfers of a specific token mint? Say I want to find all USDC transfers which happened on blockchain.

Can it be done efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some function of "efficient", yes.  You'd need to walk `getSignaturesForAddress` for the mint address. [This](https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/277/36) answer is a good place to start.

EDIT: Given that the `Transfer` instruction doesn't reference the mint address, this solution would be incomplete.  You'd probably have to do some awful graph walk to each account from each `MintTo` instruction on the mint

Comment: But `transfer` function doesn't accept `Mint` as an account, will `getSignaturesForAddress` find it anyway?

Comment: What you mean? According to docs, that method will return all transactions for a specific address, can be your address, an ATA, a mint or any address. You can use the result with getParsedTransactions to get information about each transaction. https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getParsedTransactions

Comment: @RowanStone is right. the legacy `Transfer` instruction makes no reference to the mint, instead just ensuring that the mints in the sender and recipient accounts match.  these transactions won't be reflected on the mint's history. probably have to do something awful instead (edited)

Comment: @trent.sol, thank you, I should've been more specific, as `Transfer` instruction was what prompted the question in the first place.