# How can I get wallet transactions in a readable manner

Tags: transactions, transfer, wallet

Hello I would like to get all transaction for a given wallet address with additional details like the from wallet address, the to wallet address, destination, lamport, fee, txhash, ect.. I found a post earlier that is close to what I want just need additional details. The code below was from https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/277/1452

```
const solanaweb3 = require('@solana/web3.js');
const SrchAddress = "5HcS2Qej4uPKop4pNaDHnVywx42Y2qUhceUYmbFKPG8g";

const SrchAddress = "5HcS2Qej4uPKop4pNaDHnVywx42Y2qUhceUYmbFKPG8g";
const endpoint = "https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com";

const SolanaConnection = new solanaweb3.Connection(endpoint);
const getParsedTransactions = async (address) => {
    let transactionListLength = 1
    const allTransactions = []
    const pubkey = new solanaweb3.PublicKey(address);
    let transactionList = await SolanaConnection.getSignaturesForAddress(pubkey);
    allTransactions.push(transactionList)
    while (transactionListLength >= 1) {
      const lastSignature = transactionList[transactionList.length - 1];
      const nextSignatures = await SolanaConnection.getSignaturesForAddress(pubkey, { before: lastSignature.signature });
      allTransactions.push(nextSignatures)
      transactionList = nextSignatures
      transactionListLength = nextSignatures.length;
      console.log('current:',transactionList.length);
      console.log('total:',allTransactions.length)
    }
  return allTransactions.flat()
};

getParsedTransactions(SrchAddress).then((res) => console.log(res))
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a mean feat as it is very implicit what each transaction instruction does.

A transaction instruction is a program id, an array of account metas and data. There is no way to deduce anything very human readable from this without some post-processing to decode each instruction.

You can see in this file how sollet.io does it

https://github.com/project-serum/spl-token-wallet/blob/master/src/utils/transactions.ts

Each instruction needs to be decoded, a title added and each account meta is labelled.

Another option is to use the Anchor IDL to decode the instruction when the program is an anchor program, but i wouldn't consider this fully user readable.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is not optimal. Try getting all token Accounts owned by the wallet Address then filter all transaction from specific token accounts and decode buys and sells.